# My Mac Pro (tower) running Windows 7 Ultimate says 1.99GB RAM usable?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I own a Mac Pro (Tower) with 32GB RAM that I bought about four months ago. I installed Windows 7 Ultimate and it says only 1.99GB of RAM out of 32GB's is usable?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/588nvcorqkne51v/RAM.png

Comment: Your image is a big fat 404.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac Pro's BIOS was not designed to preserve low address space for a 32-bit operating system. You should install the 64-bit version of Windows 7. It's moving all the memory out of the way of hardware mappings. Unfortunately, a 32-bit operating system can't access memory that has been remapped above the 4GB barrier.